# Integrated Graphics Performance only run 10% when render video

Tags: laptop, cpu, integrated-graphics

I have laptop Dell Latitude E5550, it have Integrated Graphics, when I render out video, CPU run 100% when Integrated Graphics Performance only about 10% as below, I was enable gpu acceleration when render. It is normal or not? Because my laptop is quite old(release about 2009). I tried install new graphic drive but nothing changed. Is there any way to increase performance?

[image]

My laptop configuration

[image]
[image]

Comment: You will find it difficult if not impossible to force an application to use more iGPU resources then it actually requires

Comment: @Ramhound I have another laptop, when i use the same application(I used Filmora) to render, CPU is about 25-30% and iGPU is 80%.

Comment: What is the GPU in the other laptop? What software are you using to "render"? What does the system requirements for that software say? It could be that the iGPU in this laptop simply does not support the features required for your software.

Comment: What's the processor in the other machine? The Intel HD 5500 is not really built for GPU rendering - & is likely slower than CPU even if you could persuade it to fully participate. GPU render is designed for 'graphics cards' not iGPUs.

Comment: Mokubai I used Filmora to render. [here](https://filmora.wondershare.com/tech-spec.html) is system requirements(least i3 2Ghz, Ram 8GB, Intel HD Graphics 5000 or later...). In other laptop is Asus Zenbook Duo 14(i5-1135G7, 16GB Ram with Intel Iris Xe Graphics). As Mokubai said, I think maybe the software is not compatible with iGPU, I tried install other version of Filmora and iGPU used 20-25%.

Comment: @manh3 - Which supports my statement that you will find it difficult to force an application to use more GPU then it requires on a specific device

Comment: @Ramhound yes, by updating all the latest drivers and trying a few different versions, using a more powerful CPU or GPU is probably the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to cpu-monkey, the hardware codec support of the
[Intel HD 5500](https://www.cpu-monkey.com/en/igpu-intel_hd_graphics_5500)
is very limited. It includes only videos with the codecs of
h264, h265 / HEVC (8 or 10 bit), VP8, VC-1, AVG and JPEG,

On the other hand, the
[Intel Iris Xe](https://www.cpu-monkey.com/en/igpu-intel_iris_xe_graphics_80_tiger_lake)
has much better codec support.

This alone might explain why the CPU is overburdened when
playing video on the computer with the Intel HD 5500 while
the GPU is almost idle.

Also, if the video you're playing is indeed in one of the supported
formats, you might not have installed a code that can use this GPU.
Installing a codec pack, such as
[K-Lite](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm),
could help as well, or using a player such as VLC that comes with
its own codecs.

Comment: The information on cpu-money was very helpful to me.  Regarding the codec, I'm not sure if it has anything to do with video rendering but this is the first time I know about the codec pack, I will install it.